# Solution to Divisibility Problem

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I have attempted to solve problem which is stated as follows:

> $2^n+1=xy$ where $n>0$ and $x,y>1$. Prove that $2^a$ divides $x-1$ iff $2^a$ divides $y-1$.

My solution is as follows:

$x$ and $y$ are evidently odd so let $x-1=2^a q_{x}$ where $y-1=2^b q_{y}$, where $q_{x},q_{y}$ are odd. So:
$$ 2^n+1=(2^a q_{x}+1)(2^a q_{y}+1)$$
$$ \implies2^n=2^{a+b}q_{x}q_{y}+2^a q_{x}+2^b q_{y}$$
$$ \implies2^{n-a}=2^{b}q_{x}q_{y}+q_{x}+2^{b-a} q_{y}\text{   }(1)$$
In the above, assuming $b>a$. Also:
$$ xy\geq x$$
$$ \implies xy-1\geq x-1$$
$$ \implies2^n\geq 2^a q_{x}$$
$$ \implies n\geq a$$
Assuming $n>a$, $2^{n-a}$ must be even, and $q_{x}$ is odd so $2^{b-a}q_{y}$ must be odd too so $b=a$. Also, $n\neq a$ because the sum on the right of (1) cannot equate to $1$.

Q.E.D.

NOTE: This is not a homework problem.

Comment: You didn't explicitly consider the case $\,a \ge n.\,$ Also you need to state how those lists of equations are related, e.g. by $\iff $ or by $\Rightarrow\,$? Without such, it is difficult to judge correctness since it is not clear precisely what is intended.

Comment: @BillDubuque : I've shown it from the $xy\geq x$ line onwards. I'll edit it accordingly, sorry.

Comment: That's a bit clearer. But once you know that $\,2^a\mid 2^n\,$ then it is trivial since then $\,{\rm mod}\ 2^a\!:\ xy\equiv 1+2^n\equiv 1,\,$ i.e. $\,xy\equiv 1\ $ so $\ x\equiv 1\!\iff\! y\equiv 1\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque : The method you have mentioned is indeed much cleaner, but I'm not familiar enough with modulo to think of using them right away.

Comment: I expanded the Remark in my answer to show how to do the same without congruences. You should learn congruences asap since they greatly simplify many problems in number theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** $\ $ After your deduction that  $\,a\le n\,$ we know $\,2^a\mid \color{#c00}{2^n}\,$ therefore

$\qquad\ \ {\rm mod}\ \color{}{2^a}\!:\,\ xy\equiv 1\!+\color{#c00}{2^n}\equiv 1\!+\color{#c00}0,\ $ i.e. $\ xy\equiv 1\ $ so $\ x\equiv 1\iff y\equiv 1\ \ \ $  **QED**

**Remark** $\  $ If congruences are unfamiliar we can eliminate them as below.

$\  \ \begin{eqnarray}\\[-1em] 2^n = xy\!-\!1 = \smash[t]{(\overbrace{x\!-\!1}^{\large b})(\overbrace{y\!-\!1}^{\large c})} + x\!-\!1 + y\!-\!1\, =\, bc+b+c\end{eqnarray}$

therefore $\ 2^a\!\mid 2^n\!= bc+b+c\ $ implies $\ 2^a\mid b\!\iff\! 2^a\mid c\ \ \ $ **QED**

Comment: Thank you for the response, but is my solution correct?

Answer (score 1):

Note that in order $2^a$ to divide $x-1$ we must have $a \le n$. Now assume $x\equiv 1 \pmod{2^a}$. Then taking the equation modulo $2^a$ we have $y \equiv 1 \pmod{2^a}$, therefore $2^a \mid y-1$.

Similarly you can prove the other side of the equivalence.

Answer (score 0):

In your solution, you want to say that $x$ and $y$ are evidently *odd*, but that's just a slip.

Your idea is good, but not carried on correctly.

What you have to prove is that, if $2^a$ divides $x-1$, then $2^a$ divides $y-1$. By symmetry, you also have the other implication.

Assume $x-1=2^aq$ for some $q$ (not necessarily odd) and $y-1=2^br$ (with $r$ odd). You have to prove that $a\le b$.

Now $2^n+1=(2^aq+1)(2^br+1)$, so
$$
2^n=2^{a+b}qr+2^aq+2^br
$$
If $b<a$, then you can collect $2^b$ on the right-hand side and get
$$
2^{n-b}=2^aqr+2^{a-b}q+r
$$
which is odd. A contradiction, because the right-hand side is $\ge3$ so $n-b>0$ and the left-hand side is even.

Comment: Sorry about the odd-even typo and thank you for the help